# Factoring out an expression to reach the answer

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

Can you tell me what is wrong of my solution that is not found in possible answers which are $1, {{5}{/}{2}}, \sqrt{2}, 2, 3 $

$$
\text { if }  \quad x+\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}=5 \quad \text {, what is} \quad x+2 \sqrt{x}=  \text { ?} 
$$

My approach is the following but I couldn't get rid of $x$

$x\sqrt{x}+2\:=\:5\sqrt{x}$

$\left(5-x\right)\sqrt{x}=2$

$5-x=\frac{2\sqrt{x}}{x}$

$5x-x^2=2\sqrt{x}$

$\color{blue}{-6x} +5x-x^{2} =\color{blue}{-6x} +2\sqrt{x}$

$x^2+x=6x-2\sqrt{x}$

$x+2\sqrt{x}=6x-x^2$

Comment: If you let $t = \sqrt{x}$, then $x\sqrt{x} = t^3$.

Answer (score 1):

$$x + \frac{2}{\sqrt{x}} = 5$$
Let $t = \sqrt{x}$.  Then $t^2 = x$ and $x \geq 0$. Therefore, we obtain
\begin{align*}
t^2 + \frac{2}{t} & = 5\\
t^3 + 2 & = 5t\\
t^3 - 5t + 2 & = 0
\end{align*}
By the Rational Roots Theorem, the possible rational roots are $\pm 1, \pm 2$.

Since $t = \sqrt{x} \geq 0$, the only possible rational roots are $1, 2$.  Substitution shows that $t = 2$ is a root, while $t = 1$ is not a root.  Hence, $t - 2$ is a factor.  We can find the remaining factor by factoring or dividing.
\begin{align*}
t^3 - 5t + 2 & = t^2(t- 2) + 2t^2 - 5t + 2\\
             & = t^2(t - 2) + 2t(t - 2) + 4t - 5t + 2\\
             & = t^2(t - 2) + 2t(t - 2) - t + 2\\
             & = t^2(t - 2) + 2t(t - 2) - 1(t - 2)\\
             & = (t^2 + 2t - 1)(t - 2)
\end{align*}
Hence,
$$(t^2 + 2t - 1)(t - 2) = 0$$
Since a product is equal to zero if and only if one of its factors is equal to zero,
\begin{align*}
t^2 + 2t - 1 & = 0 & \text{or} & & t - 2 & = 0\\
t^2 + 2t & = 1 & & & t & = 2\\
t^2 + 2t + 1 & = 2\\
(t + 1)^2 & = 2\\
|t + 1| & = \sqrt{2}\\
\end{align*}
If $|t + 1| = \sqrt{2}$, then
\begin{align*}
t + 1 & = \sqrt{2} & \text{or} & & t + 1 & = -\sqrt{2}\\
t & = -1 + \sqrt{2} & & & t & = -1 - \sqrt{2}
\end{align*}
Since $t = \sqrt{x} \geq 0$, we may discard the solution $t = -1 - \sqrt{2}$.

Since $x = t^2$, the solutions of the equation are $x = 4$ and $x = 3 - 2\sqrt{2}$.

You can substitute those values into the expression $x + 2\sqrt{x}$ to complete the question.

Comment: how could you see adding (t-2) common expression to $ t^2(t - 2) + 2t(t - 2) + 4t - 5t + 2$?(It may be a bit trivial here, but what about the following example expression?) I have difficulty in seeing these. Can you teach me seeing/getting the common expression? For example, $$a^4+2a^3-a^2-2a+1$$

Comment: Let's look at the original example.  We found that $2$ is a rational root.  Therefore, $t - 2$ is a factor of $t^3 - 5t + 2$.  We must multiply $t - 2$ by $t^2$ to obtain the $t^3$ term.  When we do so, we obtain $t^2(t - 2) = t^3 - 2t^2$.  Since we introduced the $-2t^2$ term, we must add $2t^2$ to balance the equation.  $t^3 - 5t + 2 = t^2(t - 2) + 2t^2 - 5t + 2$.  Next, we need to multiply $t - 2$ by $2t$ in order to match the $2t^2$ term.  When we do so, we obtain $2t(t - 2) = 2t^2 - 4t$, which also introduces the $-4t$ term.  In order to balance the equation, we must add $4t$.

Comment: When we do so, we obtain $t^3 - 5t + 2 = t^2(t - 2) + 2t(t - 2) + 4t - 5t + 2 = t^2(t - 2) + 2t(t - 2) - t + 2$.  In order to match the $-t$ term, we must multiply $t - 2$ by $-1$.  When we do so, we obtain $t^3 - 5t + 2 = t^2(t - 2) + 2t(t - 2) - 1(t - 2) = (t^2 + 2t - 1)(t - 2)$.